# How do I make dictionary completion look in a different file if triggered after the @ sign?

Tags: autocompletion, tags, word-processing

I have been using Vim as a research database, and I use tags in the form of `@tag` for each note, written in the second line after the title. I might have more than one tag.

How can I make dictionary completion (C-x C-k in insert mode) look in a `'tags'` when triggered after an `@` sign in insert mode?

Comment: Vim doesn't have autocomplete.  Are you using a plugin or are you referring to one of the [ins-completion](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/insert.txt.html#ins-completion) commands?

Comment: When in insert mode I press CTRL-X CTRL-K I get a drop down list of all the possible words that could complete the fragment typed so far. Perhaps the function has a different name, but the function is there, and pulls the words from the current dictionary. I would like to pull the words from a list, if the first character is the @ sign. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If you never normally use CTRL-X CTRL-K, you could change the `'dictionary'` option to point to a different file. Alternatively you could turn your tags into vim tags and use CTRL-X CTRL-T or write a user-defined completion function and use CTRL-X CTRL-U. Both of these would be harder to do, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does it have to be dictionary completion, triggered via `i_CTRL-X_CTRL-K`? If another trigger key is fine (e.g. `i_CTRL-X_CTRL-@`), you can do this:

1. Save the `'dictionary'` option value
2. Change it to point to your tags file
3. Install an `:autocmd CompleteDone` handler that resets the option value
4. Trigger dictionary completion

#### Alternative

If you don't actually need dictionary completion, just some values from a particular file, you can alternatively look at my [EntryComplete plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=5073); it provides configuable sources.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you jamessa, Matt and Ingo. I followed Ingo's suggestion and, after digging a bit around Internet, wrote a small function to toggle the dictionaries I use (English and Spanish) and the tags file (actually `.tags`). Now I can press F6 to switch from English to Spanish, and from Spanish to tags, and from tags to no dictionary. Now, on each setting, I can press  to trigger the dictionary completion, and it works great.

Answer (score 0):

In case someone is interested, here is the function:

```
"====================================================================
"  myspell.vim
"  
"  This fuction allows switching spellchecking in two languages, and
"  to have a local spell file and/or a local tags file for each 
"  project. The local spell files is called 'local.utf-8.add' and the
"  tags file is '.tags'.
"  
"  Using tags:
"  
"  The 'tags' file is a text file that lists one tag per line, organized
"  alphabetically. A tag is a keyword preceded by the '@' sign. For
"  instance @novel. This tag file is used to autocomplete tags in
"  reference files. Autocomplete is triggered by C-X.
"
"  Note: To create a '.local.utf-8.add' file, open it in Vim, save it,
"  and run: mkspell to generate the local spell file.
"
"  Note: To create a 'tags' file, go to the root folder of a given
"  project and issue ':maketags.sh'. This will create a 'tags' file.
"  Make sure that the '.local.vimrc' in the root file for the project
"  includes the line 'let g:localroot=<project's root>'
"
"  Inspired by:
"  http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Toggle_spellcheck_with_function_keys
"====================================================================
if exists("loaded_myspell")
    finish
endif
let loaded_myspell = 1

let g:myLangList  = [ "nospell",     "en_us",      "es",      ""     ]
let g:myLangName  = [ "No spelling", "US English", "Spanish", "Tags" ]
let g:myLangShort = [ "", "EN", "SP", "T" ]


function! MySpellLang()
    " Check if 'g:myLang' exists for the buffer in question, and if it
    " doesn't check if spell is set and adjust 'g:myLang' accordingly.
    if !exists( "g:myLang")
        if &spell
            let g:myLang=index(g:myLangList, &spelllang)
        else
            let g:myLang = 0
        endif
    endif
    " Spellfile
    " g:localroot can be configured in '.local.vimrc' at the root
    " level of any project. This configuration is read by the plugin
    " 'vim-localrc' (which also reads any other configuration settings).
    if !exists("g:localroot")
        let g:localroot=expand('%:p:h')
    endif
    let g:localspell=fnameescape(g:localroot).'/.local.utf-8.add'
    " Loop through languages
    let g:myLang += 1
    if  g:myLang >= len(g:myLangList) | let g:myLang = 0 | endif
    if  g:myLang == 0
        set nospell
        set spellfile=
        set dictionary=
    elseif g:myLang == 1
        set spell spelllang=en_us
        " 'set' needst to be use for '~' to be resolved here
        set spellfile=~/.vim/spell/en.utf-8.add
        set dictionary=
    elseif g:myLang == 2
        set spell spelllang=es
        set spellfile=~/.vim/spell/es.utf-8.add
        set dictionary=
    elseif g:myLang == 3
        set nospell spellfile=
        let b:localtag=fnameescape(g:localroot).'/.tags'
        if !filereadable(b:localtag) 
            " Save current directory, removing new-line and escaping spaces
            let b:savedir = fnameescape(substitute(system('pwd'),'\n','','g'))
            " Go to the local root 
            :execute "cd ".fnameescape(g:localroot)
            " Call the tag maker script
            :execute "silent !maketags.sh ".b:localtag
            " Change directory back
            :execute "cd ".b:savedir
        endif 
        exec ":set dictionary+=".b:localtag
    endif
    if g:myLang>0 && g:myLang<3 && filereadable(g:localspell) 
        exec "set spellfile+=".g:localspell
    endif 
    echo "language: " g:myLangName[g:myLang]
endf

map <F6> :call MySpellLang()<CR>
imap <F6> <C-o>:call MySpellLang()<CR>
"================================================================ EOF
```

Answer (score 0):

And this is the shell script that creates the `.tags` file:

```
#! /bin/bash
# maketags
# This program generates tags for all of the md files in and under the
# folder from which it is called as long as the tags are of the form 
# '@tag' and separated by spaces. If an arument is give, it is used
# as the name of the tag file.

if [ -z "$1" ]
then
    TAGFILE=".tags"
else
    TAGFILE="$1"
fi

touch temp.text

find "$PWD" -name '*.md' -type f -exec awk '{
        if (index($0,"@") > 0) {
            line = $0
            do { 
                tag  = ""
                iB   = index(line,"@")
                if ( iB > 0 ) {
                    line = substr(line,iB)
                    iE   = index(line," ")
                    if (iE == 0) iE = length(line) + 1
                    tag  = substr(line,1,iE-1)
                    line = substr(line,2)
                    printf("%s\n", tag) >> "temp.text"
                }
            } while ( tag != "")
        }
     }' "{}" \;

sort temp.text > tags.txt
rm temp.text
uniq tags.txt > "$TAGFILE"
rm tags.txt
```